# Why is this var still defined when the cb runs asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, namespaces

This happens to be from a Chrome extension, but I believe this is a pertinent general JS question. I have a working func like so to access local storage:

```
function loadItem(sName, callback){
    var get = {};
    get[sName] = {}; //blank obj by default.
    chrome.storage.local.get(get, function(data) {
        data[sName] && callback(data[sName]);
    });
};
```

When I invoke `loadItem`'s callback in an asynchronously-called "outer" callback, I make use of `loadItem`'s arg `sName`. Why is that defined in there? Shouldn't the asynchronous callback not recognise that var because `loadItem` has finished running and `sName` was not provided as one of the callback's own args?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is called a closure. The callback you send to `get` captures the variables in the local scope of the original function (`loadItem` in this case) so that they can still be used in the callback even after the original function has finished executing. For more information see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: I really should have know this, thanks for clearing that up quickly ;)